# npm --version - WARN onload-script failed to require onload script npm-autoinit/autoinit npm

Tags: node.js

I am installing [Foundation CLI](https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/sass-guide.html) and you are showing me the following message.

This is what I am doing:

> npm install --global foundation-cli
>
> foundation new --framework emails
>
> npm --version

```
npm WARN onload-script failed to require onload script npm-autoinit/autoinit
npm WARN onload-script Error: Cannot find module 'npm-autoinit/autoinit'
npm WARN onload-script at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
npm WARN onload-script at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
npm WARN onload-script at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
npm WARN onload-script at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
npm WARN onload-script at cb (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:289:9)
npm WARN onload-script at D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:382:14
npm WARN onload-script at D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:7
npm WARN onload-script at Array.forEach (native)
npm WARN onload-script at D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:81:13
npm WARN onload-script at f (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:17:25)
npm WARN onload-script { [Error: Cannot find module 'npm-autoinit/autoinit'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
npm WARN onload-script failed to require onload script npm-autoinit/autoinit
npm WARN onload-script Error: Cannot find module 'npm-autoinit/autoinit'
npm WARN onload-script at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
npm WARN onload-script at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
npm WARN onload-script at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
npm WARN onload-script at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
npm WARN onload-script at cb (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:289:9)
npm WARN onload-script at D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:382:14
npm WARN onload-script at D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:7
npm WARN onload-script at Array.forEach (native)
npm WARN onload-script at D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:81:13
npm WARN onload-script at f (D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:17:25)
npm WARN onload-script { [Error: Cannot find module 'npm-autoinit/autoinit'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Comment: I was finding out on the internet and I tried this command and it has been fixed, but I would like to see why that was happening, npm config delete onload-script npm-autoinit/autoinit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found a solution:

onload-script executes before any work on npm command is done, so if we create package.json file here (and block while we do it) the problem is solved.

```
npm install -g npm-autoinit
```

and After that, add npm-autoinit/autoinit as npm onload script:

```
npm config set onload-script npm-autoinit/autoinit
```

also if you need more information check the following [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-autoinit).